# Unable to access GSM List in GEOquery R

Tags: r, geo, bioconductor

I am working with a GSE set that contains 2 series matrices and would like to covert the whole thing to an expression set so that I can work with it in Limma. I have loaded the GSE using the following command:

```
> gse <- getGEO('GSE16560', GSEMatrix = T)
```

When I attempt to access the GSM list to check the platforms I get the following error:

```
> GSMList(gse)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) :
    unable to fin an inherited method for function 'GSMList' for signature '"list"'
```

So far, I checked the dimensions of the gse object and it was NULL so that doesn't help. Also, it's not a list. It also throws the same error when I call 'Meta(gse)'. I'm relatively new to these data structures and R in general so if someone could point me in the right direction it would be a huge help.

Comment: Asking on the [Bioconductor mailing list](http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/mailform/) is appropriate for Bioconductor packages like `GEOquery`. Be sure to include the output of `sessionInfo()` so that others on the list know the version R and packages you are using.

Comment: @MartinMorgan thanks, this is a great resource that I was not previously aware of :)

Answer (score 1):

your 'gse' object is a list of two expression sets.

```
library(GEOquery)
gse <- getGEO('GSE16560', GSEMatrix = T)

class(gse)
# [1] "list"

length(gse)
# [1] 2
```

You can use double brackets, `[[]]`, to access elements of the list.

```
# get the class of the first element in the list
class(gse[[1]])
# [1] "ExpressionSet"
# attr(,"package")
# [1] "Biobase"
```

I believe `GSMList` will work with objects of class 'GSE' which is what you get if you change the 'GSEMatrix' argument of `getGEO` to `FALSE`

Since you say you are new to R and these data structures, check out `?str`. It is very useful for quickly getting a sense of what is stored in an object and how the data can be indexed (if for some reason you need to do so).

```
str(gse[[1]])
# Formal class 'ExpressionSet' [package "Biobase"] with 7 slots
#   ..@ experimentData   :Formal class 'MIAME' [package "Biobase"] with 13 slots
#   .. .. ..@ name             : chr ""
#   .. .. ..@ lab              : chr ""
#   .. .. ..@ contact          : chr ""
#   .. .. ..@ title            : chr ""
#   .. .. ..@ abstract         : chr ""
#   .. .. ..@ url              : chr ""
#   .. .. ..@ pubMedIds        : chr ""
#   .. .. ..@ samples          : list()
#   .. .. ..@ hybridizations   : list()
#   .. .. ..@ normControls     : list()
#   .. .. ..@ preprocessing    : list()
#   .. .. ..@ other            : list()
#   .. .. ..@ .__classVersion__:Formal class 'Versions' [package "Biobase"] with 1 slots
#   .. .. .. .. ..@ .Data:List of 2
#   .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:3] 1 0 0
#   .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:3] 1 1 0
#   ..@ assayData        :<environment: 0x7fb344a81758> 
#   ..@ phenoData        :Formal class 'AnnotatedDataFrame' [package "Biobase"] with 4 slots
#   .. .. ..@ varMetadata      :'data.frame':   44 obs. of  1 variable:
#   .. .. .. ..$ labelDescription: chr [1:44] NA NA NA NA ...
#   .. .. ..@ data             :'data.frame':   255 obs. of  44 variables:
# ....and so on and so forth

gse[[1]]@experimentData
# Experiment data
#   Experimenter name:  
#   Laboratory:  
#   Contact information:  
#   Title:  
#   URL:  
#   PMIDs:  
#   No abstract available.

# and one more example...
head(levels(gse[[1]]@phenoData@data$geo_accession))
# [1] "GSM416241" "GSM416242" "GSM416243" "GSM416244" "GSM416245" "GSM416246"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably following GEOquery's vignette.

You need to pass "GSEMatrix=F" instead of TRUE.

```
> gse.withmatrix <- getGEO('GSE16560', GSEMatrix = T)
> gse.nomatrix   <- getGEO('GSE16560', GSEMatrix = F)

> class(gse.withmatrix[[1]])
[1] "ExpressionSet"
attr(,"package")
[1] "Biobase"

> class(gse.nomatrix)
[1] "GSE"
attr(,"package")
[1] "GEOquery"

> GSMList(gse.withmatrix)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘GSMList’ for signature ‘"list"’

> GSMList(gse.nomatrix)
.....
```